# Wait for ThreadPool to completely finish before executing the rest of the code? C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, callback, threadpool

I want to be able to know when the thread or wait call back is finished first before it executes the code after. This is my current code:

```
foreach (var ip in iPAddresses)
            {
                string loopIp = ip;

                WaitCallback func = delegate (object state)
                {
                    if (PingHost(loopIp, portNumber))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("IP Found at: " + loopIp + ":" + portNumber);
                        IPAddressesAndPortNumbersList.Add(loopIp, portNumber);
                    }

                };

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(func);

                //I want the below to be executed after the thread has finished completely
                Console.WriteLine("I have finished...");
            }
```

Solutions: I am aware that you could use a normal thread and execute this function, however, for the work I am doing, it would be way to slow to do that. I have found this to be the fastest way to complete the require work in the waitcallback function

Comment: Why don't use `Task.Run`? This is the modern way to start work on a `ThreadPool`.

Comment: ive tried that, wait to slow for my task

Comment: You don't need any threads at all, just a properly written awaitable PingHost()

Comment: hmmm, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Task.WaitAll or Task.WhenAll. Here are examples:

Task.WaitAll, as well as its overloads, when you want to do some tasks in parallel (and with no return values).

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething1()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething2()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething3())
};    
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Task.WhenAll when you want to do some tasks with return values, it performs the operations and puts the results in an array. It's thread-safe, you don't need to using a thread-safe container and implement the add operation yourself.

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething1()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething2()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething3())
};    
var things = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```